# Can't launch TensorBoard from CMD

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmd, tensorboard

I've managed to get TensorFlow (GPU) working in Python 3.5.2, but when I try to launch `tensorboard` from the command prompt, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Alex>tensorboard --logdir /tmp/data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "c:\python35\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python35\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "c:\python35\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.
```

Is there a way to launch tensorboard from Python directly, or should I try to fix tensorboard in CMD? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I ran the following script that determined that TensorFlow was installed correctly:

```
# Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================
"""A script for testing that TensorFlow is installed correctly on Windows.
The script will attempt to verify your TensorFlow installation, and print
suggestions for how to fix your installation.
"""

import ctypes
import imp
import sys


def main():
    try:
        import tensorflow as tf
        print("TensorFlow successfully installed.")
        if tf.test.is_built_with_cuda():
            print("The installed version of TensorFlow includes GPU support.")
        else:
            print("The installed version of TensorFlow does not include GPU support.")
        sys.exit(0)
    except ImportError:
        print("ERROR: Failed to import the TensorFlow module.")

    candidate_explanation = False

    python_version = sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor
    print("\n- Python version is %d.%d." % python_version)
    if not (python_version == (3, 5) or python_version == (3, 6)):
        candidate_explanation = True
        print("- The official distribution of TensorFlow for Windows requires "
              "Python version 3.5 or 3.6.")

    try:
        _, pathname, _ = imp.find_module("tensorflow")
        print("\n- TensorFlow is installed at: %s" % pathname)
    except ImportError:
        candidate_explanation = False
        print("""
- No module named TensorFlow is installed in this Python environment. You may
  install it using the command `pip install tensorflow`.""")

    try:
        msvcp140 = ctypes.WinDLL("msvcp140.dll")
    except OSError:
        candidate_explanation = True
        print("""
- Could not load 'msvcp140.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be
  installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment
  variable. You may install this DLL by downloading Microsoft Visual
  C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 from this URL:
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587""")

    try:
        cudart64_80 = ctypes.WinDLL("cudart64_80.dll")
    except OSError:
        candidate_explanation = True
        print("""
- Could not load 'cudart64_80.dll'. The GPU version of TensorFlow
  requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in
  your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 8.0 from
  this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit""")

    try:
        nvcuda = ctypes.WinDLL("nvcuda.dll")
    except OSError:
        candidate_explanation = True
        print("""
- Could not load 'nvcuda.dll'. The GPU version of TensorFlow requires that
  this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH%
  environment variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'.
  If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the
  correct driver installed.""")

    cudnn5_found = False
    try:
        cudnn5 = ctypes.WinDLL("cudnn64_5.dll")
        cudnn5_found = True
    except OSError:
        candidate_explanation = True
        print("""
- Could not load 'cudnn64_5.dll'. The GPU version of TensorFlow
  requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in
  your %PATH% environment variable. Note that installing cuDNN is a
  separate step from installing CUDA, and it is often found in a
  different directory from the CUDA DLLs. You may install the
  necessary DLL by downloading cuDNN 5.1 from this URL:
  https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn""")

    cudnn6_found = False
    try:
        cudnn = ctypes.WinDLL("cudnn64_6.dll")
        cudnn6_found = True
    except OSError:
        candidate_explanation = True

    if not cudnn5_found or not cudnn6_found:
        print()
        if not cudnn5_found and not cudnn6_found:
            print("- Could not find cuDNN.")
        elif not cudnn5_found:
            print("- Could not find cuDNN 5.1.")
        else:
            print("- Could not find cuDNN 6.")
            print("""
  The GPU version of TensorFlow requires that the correct cuDNN DLL be installed
  in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Note that
  installing cuDNN is a separate step from installing CUDA, and it is often
  found in a different directory from the CUDA DLLs. The correct version of
  cuDNN depends on your version of TensorFlow:

  * TensorFlow 1.2.1 or earlier requires cuDNN 5.1. ('cudnn64_5.dll')
  * TensorFlow 1.3 or later requires cuDNN 6. ('cudnn64_6.dll')

  You may install the necessary DLL by downloading cuDNN from this URL:
  https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn""")

    if not candidate_explanation:
        print("""
- All required DLLs appear to be present. Please open an issue on the
  TensorFlow GitHub page: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues""")

    sys.exit(-1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run it, it outputs this:

```
TensorFlow successfully installed.The installed version of TensorFlow includes GPU support.
```

Comment: Could you see the tensorboard in pip3 list? Mine shows the following two: tensorflow-gpu (1.3.0)
tensorflow-tensorboard (0.1.5)

Comment: @MaosiChen the pip3 list shows: tensorflow (0.12.0),
tensorflow-gpu (1.3.0) and
tensorflow-tensorboard (0.1.6)

Comment: I'm not sure, but is it possible the old CPU version (0.12.0) caused some conflict? Could you try to uninstall all of them and reinstall the latest gpu version? pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

Comment: After running `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` it now works. You were right, the problem was caused by `tensorflow (0.12.0)`. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run Tensorboard - From Command window (not python - but command window of Python 3.5.2)

1. Run Python command -- Point the main.py file of tensorboard! *C:\Software\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2>python C:\Software\Python\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2\Lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py --logdir=C:\Software\Python\Code\TensorFlow\logs*
2. On a WebBrowser copy the socket/url --  http://username_or_some_path:6006

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TensorFlow GPU v1.3, make sure you are using cuDNN v5.1, not 6.0.

As stated in the [install guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/install/install_windows):

> cuDNN v5.1. For details, see NVIDIA's documentation. Note that cuDNN is typically installed in a different location from the other CUDA DLLs. Ensure that you add the directory where you installed the cuDNN DLL to your %PATH% environment variable.
>
> If you have a different version of one of the preceding packages, please change to the specified versions. In particular, the cuDNN version must match exactly: TensorFlow will not load if it cannot find cuDNN64_5.dll. To use a different version of cuDNN, you must build from source.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already instlled cuDNNv5.1 and checked that it was installed correctly with the script in the above edit. I also checked that `C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v8.01` was in the system environment variables list, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

For tensorflow 2.0.0b1 (when using PyCharm) there is an executable file named `tensorboard.exe` in `PyCharmProjectFolder\venv\Scripts`  so you can run it directly from the command prompt:

`C:\Users\Alex>PyCharmProjectFolder\venv\Scripts\tensorboard.exe --logdir  /tmp/data`

Answer (score 0):

You can create new environment variable name "tensrobaord" 
and vlaue "python C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py"

[image: env variable]

and then run command tensroboard --logdir=your_log_dir